# What is the origin of the saying 'what a dish'?

Tags: phrase-origin

It seems to be used in American conversation. It's used as a compliment to someone's attractiveness.

***[Dish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dish)***:

> b : an attractive or sexy person
>   *"She's a real dish."*

(M-W)

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dish) says it is an expression from the early 20th century but it doesn’t give other details:

> that of "attractive woman" is 1920s

Comment: Similarly, someone might say "I'd like to eat him/her up", "He/she is a real treat", etc. Analogies to food are not uncommon.

Comment: She makes you drool.

Answer (score 4):

etymology of **what a dish**  [O'Conner & Kellerman](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/12/toothsome.html)

Both “dish” and “toothsome,” terms for good things to eat, have been applied to sexy people.

> From ~ 700 AD (tooth) to the Middle Ages until well into the 19th
>   century,  the expression “to (or for) one’s tooth” meant to one’s
>   taste or liking, according to the Oxford English Dictionary
>
> “Toothsome” is used to describe an attractive woman. What is the
>   origin of this usage? Is there some connection to calling someone “**a
>   real dish**”?

and the end of the article ...

> Shakespeare may have been the first to use “dish” in this figurative
>   way, in reference to sexy Cleopatra: “He will to his Egyptian dish
>   againe.” (From Antony and Cleopatry, 1606.)
>
> But this was probably just a passing metaphorical use. It wasn’t until
>   the 1920s that “dish” came to be used this way in general English.
>
> The earliest modern example in the Random House Historical Dictionary
>   of American Slang is from Variety, that fountainhead of American
>   slang: “She ought to be a swell-looking’ **dish** in tights” (Nov. 25,
>   1921).

Comment: @Barmar + on da spellcheck

Comment: Great research, thanks Barmar. Exactly the type of thing I was after.

Comment: Amy;  @Bamar edited my spelling ... I answered the question.  thanks - we work as a team here at this 'forum'.

Answer (score 1):

A similar saying is "he's a tall drink of water." I think these sayings act as metaphors comparing an attractive person with something desirable to consume. It would be a simile if you said something like that woman is as attractive as a delicious dish of spaghetti.

Comment: If someone is delicious-looking, appetizing, and makes people of the opposite sex drool at the mouth, it's easy to see how "dish" encapsulates those all-important first impressions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA lol drooling!

Comment: Many thanks to all of the respondents. I've not used this forum before- it's great! I think that yes, one can tell intuitively that the saying 'what a dish' means what we say in Australia- 'he's yummy'. However, I wanted to know how the word first came into usage and I particularly like the research done by user 'Barmar'.